# How to generate (inputs, targets, sample_weights) tuple using tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using make_csv_dataset function to feed data for model training.
As I'm using tf.keras.Model.fit function, I need to feed (inputs,targets,sample_weights) tuple for fit function from tf.data object. How can I use make_csv_dataset function to generate this tuple?(I have a weight column and a label column in my csv beside other feature columns)

Currently there are only param label_name in make_csv_dataset to indicate which is the label column, but how can I indicate the weight column for this tf.data object?

Any work around is acceptable for this question, thanks in advance!